# Is it possible to detect access to table on site db table and redirect the db query to a db shared by multiple websites?

Tags: database, hooks

I'm working on a project where I use a database that is common to all sites and another that is specific to each. Is there a way to detect access to a specific table on a contrib module (maybe using a hook) and redirect the queries to a table on the db of the shared site?

The contrib module in question is Oauth2.0 server and the table in question is the one where clients are stored, namely oauth2_server_client .

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to intercept all the query done for a database table. It is enough you change the settings for the database in the settings.php file.

Suppose that the default database definition is the following one.

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'databasename',
  'username' => 'username',
  'password' => 'password',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
);
```

If you change it as follow, you change the database used for that particular table.

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'databasename',
  'username' => 'username',
  'password' => 'password',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'prefix' => array(
    'oauth2_server_client' => 'otherdatabase.',
  ),
  'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
);
```

In this way, you are telling Drupal that for the *oauth2_server_client* table, the *otherdatabase* database needs to be used. That database needs to be accessible from the same database user (username, in my example).

Generally speaking, you can alter the query done from a module if:

- The query is a [dynamic query](https://www.drupal.org/dynamic-queries)
- The module added a tag to that query, such as in the following code

  ```
  $query = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->addTag('node_access');
  ```

In that case, you could implement [`hook_query_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7.x) or [`hook_query_TAG_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/7.x).

In your case, since you want to change the database table used for all the queries to that table, I would change the database definition in the settings.php file.

Comment: Just tried it by adding manually a new client to the server and I got this error:    PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'h.younes'@'localhost' for table 'oauth2_server_client': SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression FROM (SELECT 1 AS expression FROM {oauth2_server_client} oauth2_server_client WHERE (oauth2_server_client.server = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ) subquery; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => server1 ) in EntityFieldQuery->execute() (line 1192 of /Users/share/Public/Sites/h.younes/includes/entity.inc).

Comment: Thanks for the response; just had to grant access credentials to db.